# How to know which version of golang is used in Bazel Build?

Tags: go, version, bazel

When performing a `bazel build //...` for a golang project, is there any way I can print the golang version? If not, is there any way to configure which version of golang is used by bazel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure the Go version in your Bazel `WORKSPACE` using the [go-register-toolchains rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/toolchains.rst#go-register-toolchains), e.g.:

```
go_register_toolchains(version = "1.15.5")
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is there a way I can print it in the logs as well?